# Anti-Coagulant for Oat Milk

Tags: substitutions, vegan, oat-milk

I am trying to make my own oat milk, primarily for use with coffee (Lattes/Cappucino's etc), so I am trying my best to mimic the results of [oatly barista edition](https://www.oatly.com/int/products/oat-drink-barista-edition), which is not available to buy here in South Africa. The main problem I am having is that although the oat milk is fine when cold, when heating (i.e. steaming), it becomes thick and gloopy. Oatly use Dipotassium phosphate to stop the milk from coagulating when heated, but this doesn't seem to be readily available in shops/online (at least, not in South Africa).

Does anyone know of an alternative that I could use?

The recipe I am using is as follows:

Ingredients

- 1 Cup Steel Cut Oats
- 3 Cups Water
- 80ml Rapeseed Oil

Method

- Blend steel cut oats and the water for 3 minutes in a high speed blender.
- Extract milk with a [nut-milk bag](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KLT6X9W) and discard oat pulp
- Blend milk with rapeseed oil and a pinch of salt

Comment: Can you add to your question the recipe you are following to make oat milk?  It is interesting to me on a physics level that something gets thicker and more viscous when it is heated but is liquid when cold.  That is the reverse of pretty much anything else I can think of.  I look forward to answers here!

Comment: I've added the recipe, although it's pretty simple.

Comment: Have you tried any hydrocolloids/thickeners etc?

Comment: @zetaprime I haven't. Do you have any recommendations I could experiment with?

Comment: My go to would be Xanthan Gum

Comment: Any results on your experiments?

Comment: What about [soy lecithin](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/soy-lecithin-why-is-it-in_b_2891780)?

Comment: @zetaprime The Xanthan gum (1/2 teaspoon) turned it into sludge, unfortunately. I might have a go with a bit less next time. I just got hold of some soy lecithin (thanks @matthew-leingang), will update again once I have experimented.

Comment: Recipes I have seen for oat milk suggest that a nut milk bag is not sufficient to properly strain out the solids from the oats. When I have tried to use homemade oat milk in cooking (for a bechamel sauce) without straining fully, I think it basically turned into thick porridge, which is what happens after all when you cook oats.

Answer (score 3):

Heating oatmilk basically works on the same principle as heating any other thing with starch like a roux or thickening soup/gravy with cornstarch.

To get less thickening, add less starch i.e. less oats content per liter of water. To compensate for lack of flavor blend it with any other type of plant based milk, like soymilk (protein-based) or cashew milk(protein+fat based), or anything which is not primarily starch based. It will add nutritional value, compensate for watered down flavors (due to less oats and more water) and will not thicken upon heating.

The only other way is to use chemical additives.

Comment: I don't know if it'd be worth heating the milk ahead of time, then letting it cool (and possibly thinning it some), so it's pre-gelatinized, and there won't be as extreme a change when it's heated in the coffee

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to pre-heat the milk. I'm explaining to you what happens when you heat it.

Comment: I know you didn't.  I'm saying that might be a possible addition to your strategy.  (as it would keep it from being too thin when cold, and give you an idea of what proportion would be needed.)  Of course, the starch thickens as it cools, so it might be good to thin it partially with unheated oat milk, so as that part thickens it it balances out the thinning of the pre-gelatinized part.

Answer (score 1):

and we have an oatmeal drink that we make, but we make it different. We use less oatmeal, I would try 1/2 a cup per 3 cups of water. Then we cook it as if you were making a watery oatmeal, then you blend it. Let me know if this works.